# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libpthread.so.0" not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im trying to make an app for serial comminucation with android
im using rxtx library
Unfortunately i got a problem in my project
Thats my Logcat error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libpthread.so.0" not found
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
    at gnu.io.LibraryLoader.loadRxtxNative(LibraryLoader.java:32)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:118)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.pooya.myapplication.Connection.open(Connection.java:145)
    at com.example.pooya.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

i added the libpthread.so.0 file to my jnilibs (all subfolders) but the result is same.
please give me a hint to solve this problem

Comment: The file must be in the `java.library.path`, which defaults to the PATH if not explicitly set.

Comment: Thanks Andreas . where is it ? i cant find it on android studio

Answer (score 0):

There is no `libpthread.so` on Android, all threading functions are handled by `libc` itself. It seems the RxTx library does not support the Android platform.

You can try porting it yourself or use another solution:

- [Android Things API](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart)
- [Android USB Host API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host)
- [RxTx Android port](http://www.v-lad.org/projects/gnu.io.android/) (warning: last update 2011)
- [android-serialport-api](http://android-serialport-api) (warning: last update 2011)
- [usb-serial-for-android](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) (last update 2016)